# How to get multiple row entries through a single google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to design an inventory management form where the person would enter the stock coming in and out of the warehouse. Since at a single point of time multiple types of products(SKU) in different quantity are exchanged from the ware house. So currently in google forms I can make only a single entry in the backend sheet. I want to make a form where the user can add multiple SKU data with their respective quantities in a form which will make different rows for each in the backend sheet of google forms. Can anybody guide me how can it be done directly or via Google Apps Script.

Comment: You can't do it through Forms but you could make a custom Ui using HTMLService  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/.  You could do it as a Spreadsheet custom dialog or sidebar or through a Web App.  The spreadsheet option requires the user to open the spreadsheet and enter the data in a custom form.  The Web App option keeps the spreadsheet at arms length from the user but can update with the users input.  You decide which is best for your organization.

Comment: ok I think this would be useful. Thanks for the tip I will have a look at this. :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an simple example of creating a table and then submitting the results to a Google Spreadsheet.  You need to take a look at these Google links.  My example is run from a Spreadsheet menu option but it could just as easily be run from a Web App.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Code.gs

```
function test() {
  try {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Table").evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, "Table");
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function addRows(values) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

HTML_Table.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('CSS_Table'); ?>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="tableRows">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>SKU</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Quantify</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="buttonBar">
      <input class="inputButton" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="buttonClick(this)">
      <input class="inputButton" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="buttonClick(this)">
    </div>
    <?!= include('JS_Table'); ?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

JS_Table.html

```
<script>
  function buttonClick(button) {
    if( button.value === "Submit" ) {
      var values = [];
      var table = document.getElementById("tableRows");
      for( var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++ ) {
        values.push([]);
        var row = table.rows[i];
        for( var j=0; j<row.cells.length; j++ ) {
          var cell = row.cells[j].firstChild.value;
          values[i-1].push(cell);
        }
      }
      google.script.run.addRows(values);
      google.script.host.close();
    }
    else {
      if( confirm("Exit without saving?") ) google.script.host.close();
    }
  }
</script>
```

CSS_Table.html

```
<style>
  .inputCell { float: left; width: 110px; }
  .inputButton { float: left; width: 50%; }
</style>
```